# How to get +/- 4 words before and after a unigram in dataframe column with matched keywords from another column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe looking like

| Book_Id | Text | Matches | extract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1282 | For years I wanted to dance in a bloodmoon night and kiss the stars grazing thru ...... | dance | years I wanted to dance in a bloodmoon night |
| 1198 | The well inside the fort made by our forefathers has some incredible stories..... | made | well inside the fort made by our forefathers has |
| 2132 | It was almost dark when the spirit broke Lee free and let him start his journey towards east..... | Lee | when the spirit broke Lee free and let him |

So I want to make a python function which can loop through the matched keywords and text column and return a extract with +/-3 or 4 words in front and behind it so that the reader can understand the keyword related theme without reading the whole text.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might iterate on each "text" cell and use ".split(" ")" on the corresponding string to get a list of words.

Then it is just a matter of identifying the position of the text you are looking for and display the *n* elements before and after.

Here is a small mock-up:

```
import pandas as pd

data=["For years I wanted to dance in a bloodmoon night and kiss the stars grazing thru ......",
        "The well inside the fort made by our forefathers has some incredible stories.....",
        "It was almost dark when the spirit broke Lee free and let him start his journey towards east.....",
        "For years I wanted to dance in a bloodmoon night and kiss the stars grazing thru ......"]

matches=["dance", "made", "Lee", "Pierre"]

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["Text"])
df["Matches"]=matches

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    list_of_strings=row["Text"].split(" ")

    try:
        index_match=list_of_strings.index(row["Matches"])
        final_string=' '.join(list_of_strings[index_match-4:index_match+5])
    except:
        final_string="No Match!"

    df.loc[index, "extract"]=final_string

df
```

and the result is as follows:

```
    Text                                                Matches extract
0   For years I wanted to dance in a bloodmoon nig...   dance   years I wanted to dance in a bloodmoon night
1   The well inside the fort made by our forefathe...   made    well inside the fort made by our forefathers has
2   It was almost dark when the spirit broke Lee f...   Lee     when the spirit broke Lee free and let him
3   For years I wanted to dance in a bloodmoon nig...   Pierre  No Match!
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre for the solution, I am new to coding world, I have this exact representational dataframe  and text and keywords column. for each row I want the code to execute on the text column getting individual keyword from that row and replicate the above result in a new column. I dont want to put the text column and matches in a list and then again back it to dataframe ( as there are almost 40k+ rows with other additional columns)

Comment: How about the solution I have edited that iterates on the DataFrame?

Comment: Pierre it seems to be a elegant execution in the representational dataframe but in the original dataframe I am getting  "ValueError: 'pacemaker' is not in list " where I can see pacemaker as a keyword and also in the text column clearly. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: How about copying the line that outputs an error into the representational DataFrame and seeing if the error is still there? Maybe the two strings "pacemaker" look the same but you can have strange characters used sometimes...

Comment: I checked the output, it actually gave output pretty well till 20 lines until there was a instance where 'pace maker' was a keyword match.. can the loop skip where there it is not finding any match or the keyword is not in list

Comment: I added a try/except to deal with lines where there is no match.

Comment: First, if your issue is solved, please flag it as solved to avoid other helpers spending time on it.
Yes, you can definitely use "" to create an empty cell when there is no match.
To understand the logic behind the code, you should learn: iteration on Pandas DataFrames (df.iterrows()), string manipulations (.split(" ")), try/except, and recording data in a Pandas DataFrame (df.loc[]).

Comment: Ran into another problem where it is generating blank strings where the words are not in sort of -4 to +5 index match range.  "For years dance I wanted to in a bloodmoon night and kiss the stars grazing thru ......", - in this sentence where the keywords is nearly in the beginning or end of the sentence is giving blank strings as it cannot match thru the index specified.  Is there any way where we can add a try except to get " For years dance I wanted to in" sort of result instead of an empty string?

Comment: It is amazing to see that you have un-approved my solution whereas you had confirmed it worked, probably because I did not handle the nth additional request you have made. I think you are mistaking StackOverflow for a free-subcontracting resource. We are here to help and guide, not to do it for you...

Comment: Hi, for the amazing part here's what u said "First, if your issue is solved, please flag it as solved to avoid other helpers spending time on it." That is what I did to flag as answered as I was completely unaware of the platform operating procedures while submitting the query. Next, I did faced problem with the solution which I even was not aware of so I asked for help. There was no reply from u or any other person and I assumed this was because I flagged it as answered and nobody's noticing it. I am not mistaking StackOverflow for a FREE subcontracting platform and appreciated ur answers.